# xml.vim plugin is nonfunctional

Tags: vim

I can't seem to make any xml.vim plugin work for my vim setup. I have tried two (https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1397 and its predecessor https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=301). They seem totally nonfunctional. I have tried to view their documentation from within vim (:help xml C-d), and nothing appears except the default xml syntax help.

I have been installing them using pathogen, the standard way (e.g. `git clone https://github.com/sukima/xmledit.git ~/.vim/bundle/xmledit`). After installation, I have tried opening a test.xml file to load helptext, with no results.

I saw the other question posted here with no resolution, and it didn't help: [turn on xml.vim ftplugin in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596510/turn-on-xml-vim-ftplugin-in-vim)

So, does anyone know why this is going wrong? This is running on Ubuntu through Windows Subsystem for Linux, but I have other working  plugins (tslime and vim-slime).

**Edit:** After looking at this some more, I tried :scriptnames and the plugin (currently xmledit) doesn't appear to be in it, although the bundle/xmledit directory is in the runtimepath. Here are the contents of bundle/xmledit:

```
xmledit/
├── build.vim
├── doc
│   └── xml-plugin.txt
├── ftplugin
│   ├── html.vim
│   ├── php.vim
│   ├── xhtml.vim
│   └── xml.vim
├── Makefile
├── README.mkd
└── tests
    ├── Gemfile
    ├── Gemfile.lock
    ├── Rakefile
    ├── README.md
    └── spec
        ├── spec_helper.rb
        └── xmledit_spec.rb
```

vim version: 7.4. included patches: 1-1689, extra patches: 8.0.0056

.vimrc:

```
" mapleader definition has to be on top:
let mapleader=","       " leader is comma

" necessary for pathogen:
execute pathogen#infect()

" the good settings:
set background=dark " obvious
set tabstop=4 " number of visual spaces per tab
set shiftwidth=4 " similar
set softtabstop=4 " number of spaces added/removed while editing
set expandtab " tabs become spaces
set smartindent " do smart indenting when starting a new line
set autoindent " copies previous indent when starting a newline
filetype indent on " makes filetype-based indenting work
set number " show line numbers
set wildmenu " cyclical menu for autocompletion
set showmatch " highlight matching bracket
set incsearch " search as you type
set hlsearch " highlight search results
" turn off search highlight
noremap <leader><space> :nohlsearch<CR>
" move vertically by visual line (don't skip over wrapped lines)
nnoremap j gj
nnoremap k gk
" highlight last inserted text - doesn't work??
" nnoremap gV `[v`]
" edit vimrc with ev
nnoremap <leader>ev :vsp ~/.vimrc<CR>
" load vimrc with sv
nnoremap <leader>sv :source ~/.vimrc<CR>
" save session (reopen with vim -S)
nnoremap <leader>s :mksession<CR>

" set html indentation lower:
autocmd FileType html setlocal softtabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 tabstop=2



" for scheme/lisp:
let g:tslime_ensure_trailing_newlines = 1

" don't use, but useful to have documented:
" set cursorline " highlight current line


" idk:
"highlight Normal ctermbg=LightGray 
"syntax enable " enables syntax highlighting; not sure why this is disabled but it works anyway?

" FROM good vimrc
" CtrlP settings
"let g:ctrlp_match_window = 'bottom,order:ttb'
"let g:ctrlp_switch_buffer = 0
"let g:ctrlp_working_path_mode = 0
"let g:ctrlp_user_command = 'ag %s -l --nocolor --hidden -g ""'


" --- NOTES ---
" C-[ is escape.... ugh... 
"   also, somehow M-; is still getting through???
" mapleader is ,
" useful page: https://dougblack.io/words/a-good-vimrc.html
"   most keybindings are from here
" RETURN TO:
"   silver searcher? see good vimrc ^ for it
"   also ctrl-p. I should get both of these
```

Comment: Can you confirm the version of Vim which you are using?

Comment: [I downvoted because lacking a minimal, complete, verifiable example makes it hard to answer.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/). At least post your Vim version and [a link to] your .vimrc.

Comment: @IngoKarkat, I added some more information as per your request, although it's hard to comply with MCV example guidelines for a vim plugin build that seems to work for most people. Any advice about what else I could provide that would help fix this is appreciated. I'm not sure where the problem lies between vim, pathogen, and the plugin itself.

Comment: Thanks, downvote retracted. I don't know what's wrong, but if you don't see the plugin in `:scriptnames`, it might be worth explicitly `:source`ing it, to verify it's a pathogen issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it finally started working. I solved it by trying a few things that I thought were not necessary for Vim 7.4:

I added a `filetype plugin on` line after `execute pathogen#infect()`.

I added a `filetype off` line to .vimrc before `execute pathogen#infect()`.

I also used the `:helptags` command (which I thought Pathogen did on its own).

I don't have the patience to spend more hours identifying exactly which configuration is necessary to fix the issue, but hopefully this is sufficient for similar problems. My guess is that turning filetype plugins on is the primary culprit.